# How do I copy a list into another? Python

Tags: python, list, copy

`no = ['hello','world','spam','eggs']`

`yes = ['hey','spaam']`

How can I do something like `yes=no`?
I want the list "yes" to be exactly like the list "no".

Comment: `yes = no.copy()` or `yes = no[:]`

Comment: @AndrejKesely look at the question carefully

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by:

```py
no = ['hello','world','spam','eggs']
yes = ['hey','spaam']

yes.clear()
yes.extend(no)
```

This way, instance of `yes` will be persevere and extended with the content of `no`

Comment: The duplicated answer is already full of detail and precision, don't spread the information, if you keep your answer, the next people won't take a look at the detailed one, if you remove yours, they will

Comment: Yea, sorry. I have not whole SO indexed in my mind. I was a bit surprised with this question, but now i see we were wrong :D

Comment: I don't blame you, just telling, experience is the only way to know the SO question ;)

Comment: WIll be nice to repoen the quest, cause ehe asked how to copy one list INTO another @azro

Comment: what's the difference ? It's just have a new list that exactly he content of the first one, he did not meant INTO like addAll

Comment: @azro diference is huge here. He don't ask about NEW list, he wanted `yes` to have content of `no`. Creating new list is not a solution

Comment: it’s just the same ... it you want to have the same values but not same reference you create a new list, it you want 2 values point the same list : yes=no

Comment: the point is he already have 2 lists, `yes` and `no` he don't want a third one

Comment: There is no gain at 'not create a new one', you'll loose to empty the second and then refill it^^ For ex it you want to empty a list you'll just do : mylist = [] (so create a new one) , a new list IS NOT a new variable ^^

Comment: ```>>> id(no)
140348859871168
>>> id(yes)
140348859871040
>>> yes=no.copy()
>>> id(yes)
140348859629120``` sure

Comment: @azor it is now entity, or how ever you call it in python